# C++ looping through registry subkeys

Tags: c++, registry

I am trying to loop through keys in a specific subkey
I searched a lot but i keep getting error :(

```cpp
    LPCWSTR way = L"SOFTWARE\\PlayerBas";
    HKEY hRegAdapters;
    LONG res = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, way, NULL,
        KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hRegAdapters);
    
    for (DWORD Index = 0; ; Index++)
    {
        LPWSTR SubKeyName = new wchar_t[255];
        DWORD cName = 255;
        LONG res = RegEnumKeyEx(hRegAdapters, Index, SubKeyName, &cName,
            NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (res != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            break;
    }
```

`res` is equal to 259 aka `ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS`
I used break point to try figure the error out and `Index` equals to 1 (which means the first key was not found) but in `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\PlayerBas` there are more than 20 keys
This is confusing me O_O

Comment: Did you check whether `RegOpenKeyEx` succeeded?  `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` is a bit broad.

Comment: `RegOpenKeyEx` returned 0, yes succeeded @PaulSanders

Comment: Check you are not looking at the 32-bit registry (or the 64-bit registry) ie are you seeing the same registry as you do when using regedit ?  MS-Windows has a separate registry for 32-bit and 64-bit applications. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/registry-redirector

Comment: If the `Index` value is `1` then the first key *was* found and the loop reached its iteration statement (`Index++`); the `break` will bypass that.

Comment: @RichardCritten I didn't really understand, I use Windows key + R and then type "regedit" and I check `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\PlayerBas` and it exists with keys inside

Comment: Are you on 64-bit MS-Windows and have you built your program as 64-bit ?  On 64-bit Windows there are 2 registries one for 64-bit and one for 32-bit programs.  You could be looking at one with regedit (64-bit application) and running your program (32-bit) against the other.

Comment: I am on 64bit computer and building as 64bit program

Comment: On a side note, this code is leaking the `new[]`'ed memory for  `SubKeyName` on each loop iteration. No need to use `new[]` in this situation, unless you use `RegQueryInfoKey()` to get the max subkey name length. Which BTW, you can also use to get the subkey count

Comment: so i thought keys means values :/